# Use regular epxression to extract text from html code in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a body of html code scraped from a website using beautifulsoup. I want to use regular expressions in python to extract a portion of a url from the html code. Here is a portion of the html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/include/xbrlViewerStyle.css">
<style type="text/css">li.octave {border-top: 1px solid black;}</style>
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<style type="text/css">
li.accordion a {display:inline-block;}
li.accordion a {display:block;}
</style>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var InstanceReportXslt = "/include/InstanceReport.xslt";
var reports = new Array(161);
reports[0+1] = "/Archives/edgar/data/49196/000004919618000008/R1.htm";
reports[1+1] = "/Archives/edgar/data/49196/000004919618000008/R2.htm";
reports[2+1] = "/Archives/edgar/data/49196/000004919618000008/R3.htm";
reports[3+1] = "/Archives/edgar/data/49196/000004919618000008/R4.htm";
reports[4+1] = "/Archives/edgar/data/49196/000004919618000008/R5.htm";
reports[5+1] = "/Archives/edgar/data/49196/000004919618000008/R6.htm";
reports[6+1] = "/Archives/edgar/data/49196/000004919618000008/R7.htm";
reports[7+1] = "/Archives/edgar/data/49196/000004919618000008/R8.htm";
reports[8+1] = "/Archives/edgar/data/49196/000004919618000008/R9.htm";
reports[9+1] = "/Archives/edgar/data/49196/000004919618000008/R10.htm";
reports[10+1] = "/Archives/edgar/data/49196/000004919618000008/R11.htm"
```

I want to use regular expressions to identify "R4" to extract "/Archives/edgar/data/49196/000004919618000008/R4.htm".

Comment: Just `R4` lines?

Comment: And what did you try?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '''reports[0+1] = "/Archives/edgar/data/49196/000004919618000008/R1.htm";
... reports[1+1] = "/Archives/edgar/data/49196/000004919618000008/R2.htm";
... reports[2+1] = "/Archives/edgar/data/49196/000004919618000008/R3.htm";
... reports[3+1] = "/Archives/edgar/data/49196/000004919618000008/R4.htm";
... reports[4+1] = "/Archives/edgar/data/49196/000004919618000008/R5.htm";
... reports[5+1] = "/Archives/edgar/data/49196/000004919618000008/R6.htm";
... reports[6+1] = "/Archives/edgar/data/49196/000004919618000008/R7.htm";
... reports[7+1] = "/Archives/edgar/data/49196/000004919618000008/R8.htm";'''
>>> for i in re.findall(r'([\w./]+R4[\w./]+)', a):
...     print(i)
... 
/Archives/edgar/data/49196/000004919618000008/R4.htm
```

Comment: If you want all lines matching URLs, replace `R4` to `R[0-9]`.

Comment: That works perfectly. Can you briefly explain the regular expression?

Comment: @A.Ryan this re consists of 3 parts: `R4` in the middle and two `[\w./]+` from both sides. `R4` provides exact match. `[\w./]+` means that any word character (equals `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) or `.` or `/`, but at least one (`+`) can be in match.

Comment: @A.Ryan for the second question: you can explicitly define the following character after `R4`, and modify regular expression, for example, this way: `r'([\w./]+R4[a-zA-Z_./][\w./]*)'`.

Comment: That makes sense. Is there a way to specify that I want to capture the entire string? i.e. rather than just capture "/Archives/edgar/data/49196/000004919618000008/R4.htm", it would capture "reports[3+1] = "/Archives/edgar/data/49196/000004919618000008/R4.htm"; "?

Comment: nevermind, I found that this is accomplished by including "reports(.*?)" at the beginning of the expression

Comment: @A.Ryan to include the whole line, you can use this regex: `r'(.*R4[a-zA-Z_./].*)'`